# How do I remove lingering potions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I placed a bunch of instant harming lingering potions in my mansion and they won’t go away. It’s not the effects that I’m worried about since I’m in creative it’s just they look really bad. Any advice would be highly appreciated. Thx

Comment: I'm nor sure why people vote to close this as unclear. The question is how to remove the stuff that lingering potions create.

Answer (score 3):

Lingering potions create entities of the type "`area_effect_cloud`", so you can kill them with this command:

```
/kill @e[type=area_effect_cloud]
```

To kill only the nearest one, use this command:

```
/kill @e[type=area_effect_cloud,sort=nearest,limit=1]
```